# What is the difference between forward declaring a class and declaring a variable of class?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Suppose we have two classes Foo and Bar.
We can declare the Foo class and use its methods as following:

```
#include"foo.h"

Foo foo

class Bar{
    Bar(){
        foo.method1();
    }
}
```

And we have the forward declaration, which stands to declare the Foo class as following:

```
#include"foo.h"

class Foo

class Bar{
    Bar(){
    }
}
```

What are the main differences between the two declartions, and when the forward declaration is prefered to the normal declaration?

Comment: Useful link : https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-the-difference-between-the-declaration-of-a-class-and-a-definition-of-a-class

Comment: in your second example `Foo` is never used, so I don't understand your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ - Forward declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration)

Comment: "*We can declare the Foo class and use its methods*" Maybe try compiling your first code sample?

Answer (score 1):

In second case you don't need

```
#include"foo.h"
```

In forward declaration you just say compiler "There are Foo class somewhere. But I don't know how it look". So compiler can refer them but can't use them;

```
class Foo; //Forward declaration.

Foo* foo; // ok. Just pointer.
Foo foo;// error. Compiler can't instantiate object.
```

and

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo* foo; // ok. Just pointer.
Foo foo;// ok. Compiler can instantiate object.
```

So, in some case forward declaration can replace the inclusion of a header file.